# Emails received by day

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I need to find a way to create a record of actual emails received by day for work. I've found a way to do this using the search folders but it doesn't quite work for us because we delete emails as we deal with them, so the search folder only shows the number of emails currently in the inbox - not how many we've received. The deleted folder also gets cleared throughout the day so these can't be included in the search either. I've also used the import to Access which I found through this site, and although that's great it also only shows what's in the inbox at any given time.

is there a way to actually count the number of emails per day even if we delete as we go along? Is that something that would need to be done on the server side?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged the question with MS Outlook, so it's a fairly safe assumption that your company is using MS Exchange server. It does keep tracking logs, which include logging every email sent and received. Deleting an email is a client operation which doesn't affect the tracking.

For detailed info, please see section [Message Tracking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/message-tracking?view=exchserver-2019) in [Microsoft Exchange documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/mail-flow?view=exchserver-2019).

If you're using some other email server, you should find similar info in the server's documentation.

Comment: I thought it might be - thanks - I know we've asked IT before but didn't get very far. i'll give them these links. Thank you Peregrino69

Comment: If this satisfies, please accept the answer so it gets out of the Unanswered queue. You can always un-accept it later if it turns out to be incorrect :-)

Comment: Additional information for your reference as well and it may be helpful to you.https://practical365.com/daily-email-traffic-message-tracking-log-parser/